# Is the phantom touch issue present in resistive touch screens?

Tags: power-electronics, embedded, display, touchscreen, resistivity

Do  phantom touches (ghost touches) occur in resistive touch screens, or are they only present in capacitive touch screen displays?

Answer (score 3):

It's not present on resistive touchscreen.

The capacitive touchscreen measures the capacitance change when a finger is near the screen.

The capacitance can be affected by a lot of external environmental factors like moisture, temperature, dirt on the screen, etc.. and there is a lot of software involved to always keep it "calibrated" and ignore false positives.

On a cellphone, the screen is typically "calibrated" every time you activate the display for instance.

[image]

Resistive touchscreen, however, is made of 2 membranes that are put in contact when pushed with a finger, due to the design, they are not sensitive to the external environment and thereof to phantom touch as long as the membranes are not damaged.

[image]

The capacitive touchscreen, however, is more durable and has a better feel, it has become a prominent technology.

There are also other touchscreen technologies like ultrasonic that is sometimes used for ticket vending system like for the trains.

Comment: Yes, Thank you very much

Answer (score 1):

I’m not sure what cause you’re talking about for capacitive touch-screens.  For resistive devices, a touch is detected when two surfaces are brought into contact and that won’t ever happen without a tangible force being applied.  However it’s not impossible that the detection circuit could mistakenly report a touch because of EMC issues.  Ultimately even a mechanical push button could be susceptible to this and so it would be unwise to say that it can never happen.  The one thing you can say for certain about any device or circuit is that one day it will malfunction.